# javascript access property of just creating object

Tags: javascript, object

I would like to initialize property of object using another property of the same object which is just created using object literal:

```
var result = {
    a : 1,
    b : a
};
```

The result should be

```
{
    a:1,
    b:1
}
```

Is there any way to do this without first creating object? Using some kind of this?

Comment: What is your expected behaviour for `result.a++; console.log(result.b)` - outputting `1` or `2`?

Comment: Or in other words, do you want `result.b` to have a ***reference*** on `result.a`, or just the initial ***value*** from `result.a`?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that through a function

```js
var result = {
  a: 1,
  getResult: function() {
    return {
      a: 1,
      b: this.a
    }
  }
};
console.log(result.getResult())
```

Comment: Thank you but I wanted literal solution not dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a getter for a specific property using `Object.defineProperty`.

```js
var myObject = {};

Object.defineProperty(
  myObject,
  "b", {
    get: function() {
      return this.a
    }
  }
);


myObject.a = 1;

console.log(myObject.b)
```

Comment: ["The fundamental goal of closing duplicate questions is to help people find the right answer by getting **all of those answers in one place**."](https://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates)

Comment: Thank you but I wanted literal solution not dynamic. Good to know about custom getters.

Answer (score 0):

You could store the property first in a variable.

```js
var x=1;
var result = {
    a : x,
    b : x
};
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thank you. This is solution of choice but I still wait for someone to reveal special 'literal this'.

Answer (score 0):

### Option 1: Use a `function` instead of an object literal, allowing for  `this`:

```js
let result = function() {
    this.a = 1,
    this.b = this.a;
};

let res = new result()

console.log(res.b)
```

### Option B: Use a custom getter:

```js
var result = {
    a: 1,
    get b() {
      return this.a
    }
};

console.log(result.b); // 1

result.a++;
console.log(result.b); // 2
```

Comment: Thank you but I wanted literal solution not dynamic. Good to know about custom getters.

Comment: Option B **is** a literal solution.